# double pointer vs single pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone explain / give a reasoning to me on why the value of variable i in main function in below code snippet does not change via function test1 while it does change via test2? I think a single pointer should be sufficient to change the value of i. Why are we supposed to use double pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test1(int* pp)
{
   int myVar = 9999;
   pp = &myVar;
}

void test2(int** pp)
{
   int myVar = 9999;
   *pp = &myVar;
}

int main()
{
   printf("Hej\n");
   int i=1234;
   int* p1;

   p1 = &i;

   test1(p1);
   printf("does not change..., p1=%d\n",*p1);

   test2(&p1);
   printf("changes..., p1=%d\n",*p1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the program is ill-formed as an address of a local variable is being used beyond its scope.

Comment: I have noticed the flaw in test2 but I intentionally leave it untouched here cause it exemplifies a dangerous situation to be avoided. Thanks to all responders for the enlightening..

Comment: I suggest this interesting reading: http://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions :) At the bottom you can find a C-related question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C parameters are passed by value. This means that in `test1` when you pass `pp` a copy is made of the pointer and when you change it the change is made **to the copy** not the pointer itself. With `test2` the copy is of a double pointer but when you dereference and assign here

```
*pp = &myVar;
```

you are changing what is being pointed to, not changing `pp` itself. Take note that this behaviour in `test2` is undefined as is documented in some of the other answers here

Comment: It's not "dangerous". It's just wrong, broken, undefined behavior. It will not work except in some very rare test cases where the stars align just right to make it happen to work.

Answer (score 4):

But you're not changing the value of `i`, you're changing the address that `pp` points to, if you only want to change the value of `i` then it's enough to change your test to:

```
void test3(int* pp)
{
   int myVar = 9999;
   *pp = myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the value of a variable of type `T` you have to use a pointer on that type (`T*`). Since you want to change a pointer (`T = int*`), you have to provide a pointer to a pointer (`T* = int**`), otherwise you're only going to change the copy.

Note that

```
int myVar = 9999;
*pp = &myVar;
```

will result in undefined behavior, since `pp` will now contain the address of a local variable which isn't valid after you exit the function.

Comment: No, OP wants to change the value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `f(x)` can't change the value of `x`, no matter whether x is an int, a float, or a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
void test1(int* pp)
{
   int myVar = 9999;
   pp = &myVar;
}
```

This function is passed a pointer `pp`. The function modifies that pointer. But since parameters are passed by value, that modification is not seen by the caller.

You need to write the function like this:

```
void test1(int* pp)
{
   *pp = 9999;
}
```

The caller of this function is expected to pass the address of an `int` variable. The function then writes an `int` value, 9999 in this case, to that address. This is the key. You are passed an address, and you then write a value to that address. Your broken version simply modified the address. You were missing the indirection.

When the function returns, the caller can observe the modification to the `int` variable whose address was passed to the function. The calling code can look like this:

```
int i = 0;
test1(&i); // pass address of int variable
printf("%d\n", i); // prints the new value, 9999
```

---

```
void test2(int** pp)
{
   int myVar = 9999;
   *pp = &myVar;
}
```

Now, this is broken in a very serious way. This function does indeed return a pointer to the caller. But it returns a pointer to an object that goes out of scope as soon as the function returns. That is known as *undefined behaviour*. Don't do this. Never pass out of a function, a pointer to a local variable defined in that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* p1;

   p1 = &i;

   test1(p1);  //1st

   test2(&p1);  //2nd
```

In simple way , 1st is `pass by value` and 2nd is `pass by address`.

Description :

In first case it passing pointer is actually the copy of that `p` inside `test1` so the `pp` inside test1 is the local to that function and it's created in `test1`. You assigned the address and when comes out of function it's destroyed.

But in second case you are passing the address of the pointer to `test2` function. So the pointer `pp` in `test2` will point to the pointer `p` in main so assigning a new address to `pp` using `*pp = &myVar` will automatically set the value of `p`(since you are dereferencing the pointer). Hence when `test2` terminates still `p` will point to modified location.

Answer (score 1):

`pp = &myVar;` assigns the address of `myVar` to the pointer `pp`.  If you want to change the value that `pp` points to, use

```
*pp = myVar;
```

instead.

In answer to your second question, pass a pointer to a pointer when you want to change the object pointed to rather than changing the value of your existing object.